# Can one explain to me this Theorem

Tags: elliptic-curves, modular-forms

Can one explain to me Theorem 2. (page 3) in this link:

http://www.math.leidenuniv.nl/~evertse/siksek-modular.pdf

I am but confused about the nature the bijection defined in that result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The result in question is the celebrated Elliptic Modularity Theorem, due to [Wiles](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2118559?origin=crossref), [Taylor-Wiles](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2118560?origin=crossref) and [Breuil-Conrad-Diamond-Taylor](http://www.ams.org/journals/jams/2001-14-04/S0894-0347-01-00370-8/home.html), and initially done in the context of Wiles's solution to Fermat's Last Theorem.

I'm not sure what you're confused about in the statement of the result (which is correct).  The Eichler-Shimura construction associated to any weight $2$ newform $f$ on $\Gamma_0(N)$ with Fourier coefficients in $\mathbb{Q}$ an elliptic curve $E_f/\mathbb{Q}$ with conductor $N$.  The construction at the $\mathbb{C}$-analytic level is given in Dietrich Burde's answer: otherwise put, in the Jacobian variety you impose the relations $T_n(f) = a_n(f)$ for every positive integer $n$, so this is a kind of souped-up eigenspace construction.  The fact that the elliptic curve is defined over $\mathbb{Q}$ is not trivial and the fact that it has conductor precisely $N$ (the level of $f$) is really nontrivial.  The converse, namely that every rational elliptic curve of conductor $N$ is isogenous to a unique curve $E_f$ is the above result, which is a plausible candidate for the deepest theorem of late 20th century number theory.

Answer (score 3):

Theorem $2$ is a very deep theorem saying that all elliptic curves over $\mathbb{Q}$ are modular. This was formerly known as the Modularity conjecture, and was solved by Wiles (and Breuil, Diamond, Conrad, Taylor) in the context of Fermat's last theorem.
The point is that the map from rational newforms of level $N$ to isogeny classes of elliptic curves over $\mathbb{Q}$ of conductor $N$, $f\to E_f$, is really surjective.

Edit: The association $f \mapsto E_f$ is due to Shimura and Eichler. In the book of A. Knapp, Elliptic curves, it is explained how this map is constructed (basically to a rational newform $f$ an elliptic curve $E_f=\mathbb{C}/\Lambda_f$ is constructed, where $\Lambda_f$ is a certain lattice of periods; and it is a deep result that this elliptic curve is really defined over $\mathbb{Q}$).

Comment: @Dietrich: I edited in links to the papers in question, but this got edited out in your answer (this may amount to an edit conflict).  I wish you would at least include Breuil's name.  Also, the map is not surjective onto elliptic curves of conductor $N$: one gets only the "strong Weil curve" in each isogeny class.  It is *bijective* onto rational isogeny classes...this may be part of the OP's question.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark: yes, please feel free to edit my answer. I forgot that $E$ is only isogeneous to $E_f$, sorry.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark: Yes, in this point where I get some troubles. One other question: Does the Dirichlet series of the Hasse--Weil L-function of $C$ over $Q$ is a rational newforms of level $N$

Comment: @AR1: The "Dirichlet series of the Hasse-Weil L-function of a rational elliptic curve" (more properly one should speak of either the **Mellin transform** or the **inverse Mellin transform** of the $L$-series, but at the moment I forget which) is indeed a newform of level $N$: that is a (not obviously!) equivalent statement of the Elliptic Modularity Theorem.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark Mellin transform of a Hasse-Weil $L$ function is a newform. Just wanted to clear that up. Great answers from both you guys though.

Comment: @BrentJ: Thanks.  Of course that means that the other way around (which is just as important) is the inverse Mellin transform, which is what makes it hard for me to remember.  (It also doesn't help that I never see Mellin transforms in any other context than this...)